# react - "Reducers may not dispatch actions." after navigating to a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using

```
hashHistory.push('/home')
```

To navigate to some route on my app. However, whenever I use it I get

```
Reducers may not dispatch actions.
```

How can I properly navigate to some route without getting this error?

Comment: do you have any dispatches in code in your reducer/what it calls? Where are you calling the .push?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being a bit noob in react, this is fairly new to me
I'm calling the .push from inside a reducer

Comment: That is your problem, move the push to a react component or an action

Comment: @DominicTobias, what do I do in case the route is selected according to some HTTP request the arrives at the reducer's context.. how will I navigate from inside an action if the result arrives inside a reducer?

Comment: @user1326293 see my post below, you can perform your HTTP request and then dispatch your actions in the resolve function of the request. Assuming you are using a Promise based HTTP client.
fetch('some-url').then((response) => { // Dispatch your actions here })

Comment: FWIW, I was seeing these errors when I put a `debugger` statement inside my reducer. Seems like there are assumptions redux is making when deciding that this error condition has been met that are either incorrect, or which involve complexity in the js execution innards.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Redux, you can use the thunk middleware and react-router-redux

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

This will allow you to dispatch an action, reduce it and then dispatch another action afterwards

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

const someAction = (somePayload) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'SOME_ACTION',
    payload: { 
      somePayload
    }
  });

  // Get the updated state from the store and navigate
  let { someVar } = getState();
  if (someVar === 'some value') {
    dispatch(push('/home'));
  }
};


// Call like so
store.dispatch(someAction())
```

If you're not using redux or don't want to go that route, make sure you are not dispatching an action inside a reducer or part of that action cycle

Answer (score 2):

not the best solution but it works. inside reducer

```
  setTimeout(()=>{
           store.dispatch(
               //
             )
       },1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was dispatching an action right after my reducer, through my http request, which was set to `async: false`:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
   ...
   makeRequest();
   return {
      ...state
   }
}

makeRequest = () => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `MYURL`,
        async: false,
        data: {
           ...
        },
        success: function(response) {
           store.dispatch({
             // new action dispatch here...
          });
        }
    }
)}
```

**By changing async to true** `async: true`, I was able to dispatch an action on the successful case of my ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem after upgrading react-redux 7.1.0, redux-form to 8.3.8 and the solution is to pass mapDispatchToProps as a function not an object like the snippet below.
On some pages, it is okay with an object but if you face a problem convert it to function.
More info, read https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch.

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
    decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: 'RESET' }),
  }
}
```

If it solved your issue, please mark my answer as a correct answer.